# Hybris Flexiblesearch Today date

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to know what is the way to compare dates to today date in hybris flexiblesearch.

I've searched on the net but I could not find how. With the flexiblesearch query below I want to find the products that have been created before today, so is there some sort of a function that return the today date, maybe something similar to this query :

```
 SELECT {pk} FROM {Product} 
 WHERE creationTime < NOW
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Please make your question *specific*, so not "something like" but actually what you really want. And also, what have you attempted so far, and what is the problem that you're encountering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, current date should be picked up in java and then sent to the DB for query. But, if you're sure the date in the DB would also work fine, then

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {ItemType AS o} WHERE {o.date} <= CURDATE()
```

would work.

Answer (score 2):

There is way but it might be DB specific. On MySQL this works fine:

```
 SELECT {pk} FROM {Order as o} 
 WHERE {o.creationTime} < NOW()
```

You can also play with SYSDATE()

Comment: I tried to run this( from HAC) in an 5.5.1.0 Hybris instance which uses oracle and it does not work. Most probably it is DB specific

Comment: You can try with SYSDATE or SYSDATE()

Comment: thanks, this would work, but just on mysql, I am looking for something more general

Comment: @Hristo I tried with SYSDATE() as well and it does not work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use **timeService** bean OOTB, because this service some configuration for correction of local service timezone. Also all date time operation use this service in standard. You can set value as parameter to flex query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you could write Java code to accomplish your task, but using Java you could define regular flexible search parameters to pass a date.

For example here is a class that can fetch order created before the current time.

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.OrderModel;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchService;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult;
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.time.TimeService;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeOrderDao {

    @Resource
    private FlexibleSearchService flexibleSearchService;
    @Resource
    private TimeService timeService;

    public List<OrderModel> findSomeOrders(){
        String query = "SELECT {PK} FROM {Order} WHERE {creationtime} < ?date";
        final FlexibleSearchQuery getOrdersQuery = new FlexibleSearchQuery(query);
        getOrdersQuery.addQueryParameter("date", timeService.getCurrentTime());
        SearchResult<OrderModel> searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(getOrdersQuery);
        return searchResult.getResult();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native resource from your database, for example:

For MySQL:

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {Product} 
WHERE creationTime < NOW()
```

For ORACLE:

```
SELECT {pk} FROM {Product} 
WHERE creationTime < SYSDATE
```